# Dart how to disable select in MultiSelectContainer onChange

Tags: flutter, dart

I am looking for a way how to disable clicking for `MultiSelectContainer` in `onchange`. I tried searching on this and couldn't find a way out.

```
bool scheduleDeselect = true;

MultiSelectContainer(
                                                    controller: controllerMultipleSelect,
                                                    itemsPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                                    

                                                    showInListView: true,
                                                    listViewSettings: ListViewSettings(
                                                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                                        separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const SizedBox(
                                                          width: 10,
                                                        )),

                                                    items: List.generate(dataSchedule == null ? 0 : dataSchedule.length,
                                                            (index) => MultiSelectCard(    enabled: scheduleDeselect,
                                                          
                                                              value: index.toString() +"-"+ dataSchedule[index]['time_slot'], label: dataSchedule[index]['time_slot'],)),
                                                    onChange: (allSelectedItems, selectedItem) {


                                                      if(allSelectedItems.length>1) {

                                                        var lst = allSelectedItems[allSelectedItems.length - 2];
                                                        debugPrint("lasted:$lst");

                                                        var pos = lst.toString().lastIndexOf('-');

                                                        String previousResult = (pos != -1)? lst.substring(0, pos): lst;
                                                      
                                                       var pos1 = selectedItem.toString().lastIndexOf('-');

                                                        String currResult = (pos1 != -1)? selectedItem.substring(0, pos1): selectedItem;

                                                       if(int.parse(currResult)-1  == int.parse(previousResult)){
// I will like to apply the disable click here.
                                                         debugPrint("Correct order");
                                                       }else{


        scheduleDeselect = false;
                                                                                                          debugPrint("Incorrect order");


                                                       }

                                                      }


                                                    })
```

From the above I will like to implement disable in `if(int.parse(currResult)-1  == int.parse(previousResult)){ }`. Thanks in advance.